# C# Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I know these warnings are probably pointless.. But anyway I could get rid of them?

I got 7 of these warnings.

`Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first`

This has something to do with the OR operator `|`

I highlighted what gives off the warnings.

```
int result = (int)ror((uint)(v76 ^ (v75 | 0x862D63D3)), (uint)(BitConverter.ToInt32(v4, 72) ^ 0x22));

int v11 = (int)rol((uint)(int)((v8 & v10 | ~v10 & 0xEFCDAAC9) + v3[2] - 1126481991), 17);

int v144 = (int)rol((uint)(int)((v141 & v143 | ~v143 & 0xEFCDAAC9) + v3[2] - 1126481991), 17);

int v77 = (int)(`BitConverter.ToInt32(v4, 52) | 0x96C35837`);


BitConverter.GetBytes((int)(v30 & 0x870DEA8A | v29)).CopyTo(v2, 32);

int temp24 |= (int)(BitConverter.ToInt32(v3, 48) | 0x96B4A1B4);

int v17 = (int)(BitConverter.ToInt32(v3, 12) | 0x83868A1D);
```

Comment: This can get additionally confusing with a mix of signed and unsigned shorts and ints -- just think about which type your sub-expressions will be promoted to and follow the advice in the accepted answer. Exercise for reader: try and get "uint x = (<ushort> << 16) | <short>" to compile.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A quick Web search shows [the official documentation for the warning](https://web.archive.org/web/20141027045157/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdc6717a(v=vs.71).aspx), which comes with an explanation:

> The compiler implicitly widened and sign-extended a variable, and then
>   used the resulting value in a bitwise OR operation. This can result in
>   unexpected behavior.

The problem is that the expression `v75 | 0x862D63D3` is of the form `int | uint`. This is computed by promoting both sides to `long`. If you really want sign extension, write `(ulong)(long)v75 | 0x862D63D3`. If you really want zero-extension, then write `(uint)v75  |0x862D63D3`.

```
class Program {
 public static void Main()
 {
  int v75 = int.MinValue;
  System.Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", v75 | 0x862D63D3);
  System.Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", (ulong)(long)v75 | 0x862D63D3);
  System.Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", (uint)v75 | 0x862D63D3);
 }
}
```

This program prints

```
ffffffff862d63d3
ffffffff862d63d3
862d63d3
```

As you can see, the compiler defaults to the first interpretation, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I'm seeing this error with `long | int` ... no signed/unsigned mismatches that I can find ... the warning goes away when I explicitely cast the `int` to a `long`, but then the IDE also informs me that the explicit cast is "redundant" since casting from `int` to `long` is supposed to be implicit.
I guess it can't make up its mind. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try casting v75 and other variables being ORed with unsigned hex values to uint:

```
((uint)v75 | 0x862D63D3)
```

or declare the variables as `uint` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

if you do OR operation for int and long variable, then system cast int to long.
Exist two way for it  :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"int.MinValue  = {Convert.ToString(int.MinValue, 2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"long.MinValue = {Convert.ToString(long.MinValue, 2)}");

        Console.WriteLine();

        long cast1 = int.MinValue;                   // !!!
        long cast2 = unchecked((uint)int.MinValue);  // !!!

        Console.WriteLine($"default cast = {Convert.ToString(cast1, 2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"custom  cast = {Convert.ToString(cast2, 2)}");

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"default long OR int = {Convert.ToString(long.MinValue | int.MinValue, 2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"custom  long OR int = {Convert.ToString(long.MinValue | unchecked((uint)int.MinValue), 2)}");
}
}
```

Result:

```
int.MinValue  = 10000000000000000000000000000000
long.MinValue = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

default cast = 1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
custom  cast = 0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000

default long OR int = 1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
custom  long OR int = 1000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000
```

How result you want?