# Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I just tried installing Visual Studio 2015, and when trying to compile an old project, I got the warning

> CS0675 Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider
>   casting to a smaller unsigned type first

for a piece of code that does not give the same warning when compiling in Visual Studio 2013. I found out that all it takes to reproduce is this very simple code:

```
short a = 0;
int b = 0;

a |= (short)b;
```

Now, I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328052/c-sharp-bitwise-or-operator-used-on-a-sign-extended-operand-consider-casting-to), I have read [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/29/bit-twiddling-what-does-warning-cs0675-mean.aspx) on this issue, and I quickly read up on [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), but my understanding is that sign extension happens when you cast from a signed number type consisting of a smaller number of bits to one with a larger number of bits, such as `short` to `int` for example.

But since I'm casting from an `int` to a `short`, no sign extension should happen if I'm not mistaken. The fact that this does not issue a warning in earlier versions of Visual Studio, it leads me to believe that this must be a bug in the Visual Studio 2015 compiler (Roslyn). Am I misunderstanding how sign extension and/or the compiler works here, or is this most likely a compiler bug?

### Update

Jon Skeet pointed out that there actually is indeed a sign extension happening since the `|` operator isn't defined for `short` and so there's an implicit cast to `int` before the result is cast back to `short` again. However, the compiler shouldn't have issued this warning since the cast is harmless. There was a bug in the Roslyn compiler as pointed out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just a bug. The code to detect and report this error was added very late in the VS2015 development (see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/909 and https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/2416) and it detects too many cases compared to VS2013. There is now a bug report (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4027) to repair this.

Comment: And another one here. You can add it to your answer: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1528317/visual-studio-2015-explicit-casting-int-to-short-in-a-bitwise-expression-causes-error-cs0675-bitwise-or-operator-used-on-a-sign-extended-operand-consider-casting-to-a-smaller-unsigned-type-first

Comment: Seems to be fixed with [VS2015 Update1 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/11/30/visual-studio-update-1-rtm.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

Sign extension *is* happening, but possibly not for the obvious reason, and not in a worrying way, IMO.

This code:

```
a |= (short) b;
```

is equivalent to:

```
// No warning here... (surprisingly, given that `a` is being sign-extended...)
a = (short) (a | (short) b);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
// No warning here...
a = (short) ((int) a | (int) (short) b;
```

because the `|` operator isn't defined for `short` operands anyway. Both operands are promoted to `int`, then the result is cast back to `short`.

It's not clear why the compiler decides to warn in this case, but there *is* sign extension occurring... albeit in a harmless way.

Note that you get the same warning if no `int` variables are involved at all:

```
short a = 10;
short b = 20;
a |= b; // CS0675
```

Given the way that the `|` operator works with casts, this looks entirely harmless to me. I'm not sure whether I'd call it a compiler *bug*, but it definitely looks like non-ideal behaviour to me. Will ping C# compiler team members to see what I've missed :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'd actually misread the question, and just changed my answer a bit. It's all a bit odd, I agree.

Comment: *`|` operator isn't defined for*... `short` operands?

Comment: @Rawling: Nope. Only `int`, `uint`, `long` and `ulong`. Operands are promoted to one of those types first. As an example, try `short x = 10; short y = 20; short z = x | y;`

Comment: @JonSkeet I think that he was pointing to a typo :D your post says "because the | operator isn't defined for int operands anyway. "

Comment: @JulienRoncaglia: Ah, whoops - fixed.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I wasn't aware that the | operator wasn't defined for `short` and that an implicit cast to `int` was happening. That was a neat insight. However I'm giving the "accept" to Gafter as I feel that most directly addresses the issue I was having. But thanks for a great answer.

Comment: @HannesJohansson: Yes, it's always likely that a member of the C# team in MS will have a more useful answer for something like this :)