# How to properly refactor C# Bitwise-or operator usage in order to get rid off Compiler Warning (level 3) CS0675

Tags: c#, refactoring, compiler-warnings, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I need to refactor following code, so it will not produce compiler warning:

```
short bi_buf;
int bi_valid;
int value;
....
bi_buf |= (short)((value << bi_valid) & 0xffff);
```

If compiler Warning level is set to 3 or higher it will produce following error:

```
Error   CS0675  Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first
```

I understand that this is possible to fix by casting, but will appreciate someone experienced with bitwise operator to do it to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542256 Basically it's a compiler bug...

Comment: No sign of this warning in VS2015 RTM, update your VS version.

Comment: I tried using VS2015 RTM and it behaves the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a compiler bug, one that has been reported and fixed (I reported it only to find it had been fixed already). See [bitwise-or-operator-used-on-a-sign-extended-operand-in-visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542256/bitwise-or-operator-used-on-a-sign-extended-operand-in-visual-studio-2015?lq=1)

But if you want to work around it in the meantime, you can fix it like so:

```
 bi_buf;
 int bi_valid;
 int value;
 ....
 bi_buf = (short)((int)bi_buf | (int)((value << bi_valid) & 0xffff))
```