# Bug in compiler or misunderstanding? Or operator on shorts

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, roslyn, c#-6.0

I have a line of code that is giving me an warning message (CS0675) in VS2015, but not in 2013.

```
shortValue |= (short)anEnum;
```

> Warning   CS0675  Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand;
>   consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first. The compiler
>   implicitly widened and sign-extended a variable, and then used the
>   resulting value in a bitwise OR operation. This can result in
>   unexpected behavior.

Obviously what is happening is the enum and the short are being extended to an int, the or operator applied, and then the result assigned the result to the short.

If I change the code to `shortValue = shortValue | (short)anEnum;` I get a compiler error CS0266.  But the bitwise OR should be valid for shorts (in both cases I believe).  If I hover the mouse over the `|` it shows as an int operator, am I missing something or should I report this as a bug?

PS: I know I can eliminate the warning/error by using `=` instead of `|=` and casting the result to a short.

Comment: See also [Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand in Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542256/) and other threads.

Comment: This is a bug in VS2015 and will be fixed in VS2015 Update 1. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4027 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the C# specifications (specifically in "Integer logical operators") you'll see that there's only a definition for `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong` for the logical OR operator:

```
int operator |(int x, int y);
uint operator |(uint x, uint y);
long operator |(long x, long y);
ulong operator |(ulong x, ulong y);
```

Also, in [Bit twiddling: What does warning CS0675 mean?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/29/bit-twiddling-what-does-warning-cs0675-mean.aspx) Eric Lippert states that:

> "There are bitwise-or operators defined on `int`, `uint`, `long` and `ulong`"

The operator IS valid for `short`, but only in the sense that the short value can be extended to `int`. The return value of that operator however, is (at least) an `int`.

So, technically speaking, according to the specs, this doesn't seem to be a bug as using `|=` does extend the signed value to int, which gives a warning and the regular `|` results in an `int` that needs to be cast down to be assigned to a `short`.

**However**, since the compiler can in fact know that both operands are originally `short`s, both get extended to `int` and the result will eventually be stored back into a `short` it doesn't really matter that the operands are extended. The extension will be lost by the cast from `int` to `short`.

So, either the VS2013 compiler was smarter with its warnings than the VS2015 one or the VS2015 fixes a bug and warns where VS2013 failed to. Only the people behind the compiler can answer that but I assume it's indeed a bug (EDIT: [and it is](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4027)).

Comment: I think I'll report it as a bug anyway, as there is no way of using |= without a warning or error in 2015, but 2013 was happy with it (so either it was a bug in 2013, or they deliberately suppressed the error, and I suspect the later).

Comment: @jmoreno I wouldn't really call it a bug, but I agree that VS2013 is right here and VS2015 is not. I've updated the answer a bit to explain that.

Comment: @jmoreno And it was apparently fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4027